# Make two columns the same height using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I am using Flexbox to create a two column layout. One column has simple content with a color background. The other column has an image that should cover the full height/width of the div.

These two columns should both be the height of the `.content` div (which will grow/shrink based upon screen size). If there is any overflow of the `.marketing-image img` it should be cut off. I would like to solve this using CSS/SCSS only, no JavaScript please :)

Any help is appreciated!

Here is my code: https://codepen.io/erbanach/pen/bMdOKM

```css
.block-marketing {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.split {
  width: 50%;
}

.left {
  order: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.right {
  order: 2;
  display: flex;
}

.marketing-image {
  flex: 1;
}

.marketing-image img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 50px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-marketing">
  <div class="split left">
    <div class="marketing-image">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="split right">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer finibus odio id magna pharetra iaculis. Praesent faucibus placerat porttitor. Donec dignissim nibh et commodo luctus. Integer dictum ultricies urna ut viverra. Vivamus tempor iaculis
        rutrum. Duis suscipit libero sit amet quam vehicula, sit amet ullamcorper felis commodo. Aliquam eu fringilla lectus, a laoreet nisi. Etiam accumsan ex libero, eget posuere dolor sodales in.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply remove `align-items: center` from your `.block-marketing` selector and add `height: 100%` to the image:

I've forked and updated your codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QrbzXz

Answer (score 0):

If you may use grid, simply

```
.block-marketing {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.marketing-image {
  height: 100%;
  img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.content {
  padding: 50px;
  background: pink;
}
```